# No "droidgap" file in PhoneGap download?

Tags: android, cordova

When I download the latest PhoneGap zip there are several files and folders (including an Android folder), but there is no `droidgap` file (normally `bin/droidgap`).

Don't I need a droidgap file to run from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

droidgap is not in the install zip from http://www.phonegap.com/download, but it is in now on [svn](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-android/trunk/framework/src/com/phonegap/DroidGap.java).

droidgap makes some things easier from the command line, but it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: The answer above is now out of date as PhoneGap has moved to Callback. I have downloaded the latest from CallBack but there is no Droidgap in there either so this question should be considered as not answered.....

Comment: Updated answer to new links in the renamed "callback" repositories

Comment: @PaulBeusterien links give 404

Answer (score 2):

That file is now in org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
As a side note, if you can't find an asset, just type it in and then do a quick fix on it. (right click)

Answer (score 0):

I came across such issues too.
go to https://github.com/jonathanstark/phonegap-android, search the droidgap file in the bin folder there, download it and save it with .rb then you are good to go.